# strip package info when logging variable name

Tags: java, logging

`Log.d("status", "my variable is " + foo);` will render something like:

> my variable is com.thisismyapplicationname.thisismyprackagename.Foo@1abcdef

This is taking up a lot of space and making things difficult to read, so is there a way to make the Log statement just output this?:

> my variable is Foo@1abcdef

I don't need the application or package information.

Comment: This is `toString`, doesn't have much to do with the logger. Write your own implementation.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis has the answer. I didn't think of `toSring()`. It's ugly, but `foo.toString().substring(foo.toString().lastIndexOf(".") + 1)` works. Thanks!

Comment: I meant for you to override `Foo`'s `toString` implementation, if you own it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Brilliant. `public String toString() { return (super.toString().substring(super.toString().lastIndexOf(".") + 1)); }` works perfectly! And all my logging statements everywhere have just been 'fixed' without having to do anything. That was easy.

Comment: Or `public String toString() { return "Foo@" + System.identityHashCode(this); }` (or more generic `getClass().getSimpleName()` instead of Foo)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis would you like to submit your comment as the answer? i think it would be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is @SotiriosDelimanolis excellent answer from the comments. I upvoted all his comments and gave him a week to respond, but I really think posting his answer to this question will help the community.

The logging text is coming from `toString()`, so you can solve this problem by overriding that method:

```
public String toString() {
    return (super.toString().substring(super.toString().lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
}
```

This accomplished what I wanted (removing all the package information) but you can obviously do whatever with it. Thank you @SotiriosDelimanolis!